# puppet overriding file resource on a module

Tags: linux, automation, centos, puppet

i am using this CIS module [arildjensen/cis-puppet](https://github.com/arildjensen/cis-puppet)

and want to override the `/etc/profile` file declaration on the CIS module

so i created this new manifest, following this [post](http://www.opencredo.com/2012/10/25/overriding-puppet-resources-with-class-inheritance/)

```
class profile::hadoop::settings inherits cis {

      file { '/etc/profile':
        ensure => 'file',
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0600',
        source => 'puppet:///modules/profile/hadoop/etc/profile',
      }
  }
```

however this still gives the error

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: File[/etc/profile] is already declared in file /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-ab9b45e51a68912cdc576c81d46a2260/profile/manifests/hadoop/settings.pp:9; cannot redeclare at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-ab9b45e51a68912cdc576c81d46a2260/cis/manifests/linuxcontrols/c0076.pp:12 on node server.localdomain
```

Answer (score 14):

The syntax for a resource override is different from the syntax for a resource declaration.  You're looking for this:

```
class profile::hadoop::settings inherits cis {

    File['/etc/profile'] {
        ensure => 'file',
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0600',
        source => 'puppet:///modules/profile/hadoop/etc/profile',
    }
}
```

Syntactically, it's a resource reference (which makes sense) with an appended list of property overrides.

That's the old-school way, of course.  Since at least Puppet 3.0, you can also perform overrides with a collector, in which case you don't need class inheritance:

```
class profile::hadoop::settings {
    include 'cis'

    File<|title == '/etc/profile'|> {
        ensure => 'file',
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0600',
        source => 'puppet:///modules/profile/hadoop/etc/profile',
    }
}
```

See [the docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/lang_datatypes.html#resource-references) for full details.